# Entity Framework - Saving list of records from a datatable to a SQL Server database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am a beginner at EF, I have my list of records in a datatable, I want to save these records from datatable to a SQL Server table using Entity Framework.

```
// My datatable which has my list of records is DT
foreach(DataRow dr in DT.Rows)
{
   savetoDB((Int32)dr["EmpId"], dr["DisplayName"], "CSE");
}

Private void savetoDB(int empId, string displayName, string Dep)
{
    using (MYDB em = new MYDB)
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.EmployeeId = empId;
        emp.DisplayName = displayName;
        emp.Department = Dep;
        Employee.Add(emp);
        em.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

This works as expected but I am looking if there is any better approach instead of looping through each row in thr datatable and saving it. If there are 30 rows my method gets called 30 times and `emp.SaveChanges();` is executed 30 times.

Remember I also have static value department.

Comment: You can use bulk insert, here is the good tutorial for the same- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173837/BulkInsert-with-the-Entity-Framework or you can make a SP and call it through context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first piece of advice I'd like to say It's not necessary to call ***`SaveDB`*** method in ***`foreach`*** iteration. you just need to create a ***`List<Employee>`*** and in foreach add data table rows to this list and after iteration pass the ***`List<Employee>`*** to the ***`SaveDB`*** method.

```
var employees = new List<Employee>();
foreach(DataRow dr in DT.Rows)
{
   employees.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = (Int32)dr["EmpId"] ...})
} 
SaveDB(employees);
```

With this scenario, you just call ***`SaveDB`*** method **one time**.

and for resolving the problem of calling ***`SaveChanges()`*** for several times, You just need use the ***`AddRange()`*** method, and pass ***`employees`*** to it.

```
Private void savetoDB(List<Employee> employees)
{
     using (MYDB em = new MYDB)
     {
        em.Employee.AddRange(employees);
        em.SaveChanges();
      }
 }
```

for more information about ***`AddRange()`*** you can follow this [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/addrange-removerange.aspx).

good luck.